# Changing the default intro.js tooltip placement

Tags: javascript, html, css, intro.js

I am using intro.js to set up a tour of my website, and I would like to set the default placement of the tooltip (when not attached to any element) near the top of the page instead of the vertical center.

It doesn't look like there is an option to set it directly, but is there a way to do it changing the CSS? (or by editing the source, although that's kind of a last resort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do something similar. Not elegant, but it works.

In the API documentation, there's an [onafterchange](http://introjs.com/docs/intro/api/#introjsonafterchangeprovidedcallback) method. Give it a callback function and it will get fired each time a step is displayed.

If the tooltip has a target element, the callback's argument contains that element. If the tooltip doesn't have an element, the argument contains an element with the class *introjsFloatingElement*. So, you just need to check for the presence of that class on that element. If it does, you can tweak the styles of the tooltip elements.

```
var help = introJs();
help.onafterchange(function(targetEl){
    targetEl = jQuery(targetEl);

    // check if it's a floating tooltip (not attached to an element)
    if(targetEl.hasClass('introjsFloatingElement')){

        // adjust the position of these elements
        jQuery('.introjs-tooltipReferenceLayer').offset({top : 120});
        jQuery('.introjs-tooltip').css({
            opacity: 1,
            display: 'block',
            left: '50%',
            top: '50%',
            'margin-left': '-186px',
            'margin-top': '-91px'
        });
        jQuery('.introjs-helperNumberLayer').css({
            opacity: 1,
            left: '-204px',
            top: '-109px'
        });
    }
});

// add your steps
// ...

help.start();
```

Note:

- I first tried [onbeforechange](http://introjs.com/docs/intro/api/#introjsonbeforechangeprovidedcallback), but that didn't work. Not sure why.
- At first, I tried to adjust the *introjs-tooltipReferenceLayer* element only, but the nested elements (*introjs-helperNumberLayer* and *introjs-tooltip*) were not positioned correctly on first display. I had to inspect those elements on subsequent displays to get the proper stylings.
- Tested with intro.js 2.5.0. Element classes aren't part of the api spec, so I don't know how future-proof this solution is.

Comment: Thanks, checking the class is and then setting it using `onafterchange` is a good idea. I had gotten it working somewhat by editing the source CSS but this is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the intro.js documentation. you should be able to just add this line of code to your script.

```
introJs().setOption("tooltipPosition", "top");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this option only appears to set the default position for tooltips relative to the element they are attached to. It doesn't seem to have any effect on the placement of a tooltip not attached to anything.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Maybe you can use the same command to set `tooltipClass` and change the position in the CSS. But this only works if you can use `setOption` on each individual tool tip.

Comment: Thanks for the second idea, but it's not working either. You can set `tooltipClass` independently using the `steps` array ([see here](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/programmatic/index.html)), but it doesn't work for position settings because the intro.js javascript overrides any custom class positioning using `style` tags.